# Jest - test try-catch block

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to test a try catch block using Jest. E.g.

```
// filename: foo.js

const foo = () => {
  let js = 'somejs'
  try {
    eval(js)  
  } catch (e) {
    document.location = 'redirect/to/page'
    return false
  }
  return true
}

export default foo
```

Do you mock `eval` (not my choice to use eval. It's my bosses code) and then get it to throw? If so, how would you do that? E.g.

```
eval = jest.fn()    // doesn't work
```

So the test code might be:

```
// filename: foo.spec.js

import foo from './foo'
eval = jest.fn()

describe('foo', () => {
  describe('when eval succeeds', () => {
    it('performs an eval', {
    const result = foo()
    expect(result).toEqual(true)
  })
  describe('when eval fails', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      eval.mockImplementation(() => {throw 'error'})
    })
    it('catches the error and redirects', () => {
      const result = foo()
      expect(result).toEqual(false)
    })
  })
})
```

What would the mocking and test code look like?

Comment: First [`eval()` is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/q/86513/1078886) and most problems can be solved without. `eval()` appears to be a non-unforgeable function, thus is can be overwritten _on the `window` object_ (just assigning to eval does not help, you've to replace the global object's property; crude example: `window.eval = ...`). This can be done with mocking facility of your choice. Here's an answer elaborating a bit on mocking [`location` attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36678937/1078886), though it uses Sinon for mocking the principal is the same for other mocking tools.

Comment: No arguments re `eval`. It's my bosses code. I can't alter it. But I don't know how to mock out `window` using Jest when it is not wrapped in a helper function (again, it's my bosses code, not mine). From your answer at the other SO question, It sounds like you simply can't mock `window` directly, unless it is wrapped in a helper function. If you can mock it, how do you do that in Jest? [Here is a link to an unanswered question that deals directly with this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200395/jest-mock-window-or-document-object):